# Can you add the "New Note" global action to the Contact Activity Composer?

Tags: actionsupport, notes, global-actions

I have been tasked with adding the New Note" global action to the activity composer on the action and case pages. I have added the field to the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" in the object's page layout, but it is still not showing up. Is there any way of adding these?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to move 'New Note' action button under activity and it is always located in the record's highlights panel.

[image]